# How to add two queries together in one table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two SQL queries that I want to add together on the same table. I want display a table that shows the JuniorCount, SeniorCount, and DeptID.

Right now I have the queries that count the juniors/senior with dept class ECE but I'm not sure how to add them together to display in separate columns as well as the deptid.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as JuniorCount
FROM (SELECT Class, DeptID FROM tblStudent WHERE Class = "Junior" AND DeptID = "ECE")


SELECT COUNT(*) as SeniorCount
FROM (SELECT Class, DeptID FROM tblStudent WHERE Class = "Senior" AND DeptID = "ECE")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you need

```
SELECT DeptID,
sum(case when Class = 'Junior' then 1 else 0 end) as JuniorCount,
sum(case when Class = 'Senior' then 1 else 0 end) as SeniorCount
FROM 
tblStudent WHERE DeptID = 'ECE'
Group by DeptID
```

In MS ACCESS

```
SELECT DeptID,
sum(IIF(Class = 'Junior' ,1,0)) as JuniorCount,
sum(IIF(Class = 'Senior' ,1,0)) as JuniorCount
FROM 
tblStudent WHERE DeptID = 'ECE'
Group by DeptID
```

Comment: Sorry how do you do this in Access?

Comment: See my edited code. I have added code for MS ACCESS as well

Comment: @jarlh Thanks. Fixed it

Comment: @Madhivanan, commas, i.e. plural.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `GROUP BY` to get the sums per Class.

```
SELECT Class, COUNT(*)
FROM tblStudent
WHERE Class IN('Junior', 'Senior')
AND AND DeptID = "ECE"
GROUP BY Class
```

(The `CLASS IN` part can be omitted if you only have Juniors and Seniors in the table.)

Comment: This doesn't display the DeptID and I need the JuniorCount and SeniorCount as separate columns not one single column

Comment: @ChaCol, simply add DeptID to SELECT list and to GROUP BY. (Still separate rows.)

Comment: Yeah but how do I separate the Class into columns instead of rows? Like I want a column that says JuniorCount with the number beneath it and a second column SeniorCount with the number beneath it